# Why this isn't changing the background to an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I wrote this code in CSS

'body {
background-image: url('C:\Users\HerOx\Desktop\Proyectos Programación\gata conquistadora\imagenes olivia\olivia-demonio.png');

}'

And it isn't working.

Comment: Your browser is likely enforcing security restrictions that prevent reading of arbitrary files in your filesystem. Serve the image with a proper HTTP server and point your code to it that way.

Comment: You can read up about what consitutes a url in this context here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solution for this would just to put the image in the same folder as the code, then write the image file there instead of going through the entire computer.

```
body{
  background-image: url("olivia-demonio.png");
}
```